# Connecting to Exchange via EWS API - Kerberos authentication - from Windows

Tags: python, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, kerberos, exchangelib

Im need to connect to Exchange Server (via EWS api) from **Windows** and download a message with attachment. So I created the script below. Exchange using Kerberos for authentication. 
The main questions are:

1. This code will be working? Or should I use another modules to connect? Mainly the part about connecting to Exchange using the Kerberos.
2. On which thing Im need to focus or should I check before?

I using Exchangelib for connect to Exchange.**The problem is related to Exchangelib, anyone using this in similar case like me (connecting to EWS via Kerberos from Windows)?**

```
from exchangelib import DELEGATE, Configuration, GSSAPI
from exchangelib.protocol import BaseProtocol, NoVerifyHTTPAdapter
from exchangelib import Account, ServiceAccount
import extract_msg
import logging.handlers
import os
import winkerberos as kerberos
from datetime import datetime


#connecting to Exchange

user='administrator@xy.test'
password='secret!@#'
BaseProtocol.HTTP_ADAPTER_CLS = NoVerifyHTTPAdapter

config = Configuration(
    server='172.16.41.206',
    credentials = ServiceAccount(username=user, password=password),
    auth_type = GSSAPI
    )

account = Account(
    primary_smtp_address='administrator@xy.test',
    autodiscover=False,
    config=config,
    access_type=DELEGATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Kerberos auth, the code expects a valid ticket to exist in your environment, so your Python code does not need the username and password. Just use `ServiceAccount('', '')` as described in https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#setup-and-connecting

I don't know how to create or check for a valid Kerberos ticket on Windows. On Linux I would use `kinit` and `klist`.

Please note that Kerberos support in exchangelib is untested and experimental.